# Has anyone used a DiCAPac waterproof case? Looking for point and shoot dust protection

Tags: point-and-shoot, equipment-protection, dust, camera-cases

Trying to figure out a way to bring my new Canon S100 to Burning Man, but worried it won't stand up to the harsh dust of the desert like a sturdier SLR would. Has anyone tried one of these waterproof cases? I'm a bit worried the camera will be barely usable through the thick plastic, but short of ziplock bags don't see any affordable alternatives.

http://www.dicapac.com/products/products.asp?idx=72&bcate=1&scate=3&tcate=0

I may just end up bringing out my 20D instead since it's getting old anyways, but I love this little camera!

Comment: Just ordered one, so I'll see how it goes and report back!

Answer (score 1):

I'd think about getting an Olympus tough:

http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/search?Ntt=olympus+tough&N=0&InitialSearch=yes

You can buy one for not much more than a waterproof case, and the ergonomics will be a lot better.  I have a previous-previous generation of the Olympus waterproof, shockproof, etc. cameras, and it's great for those times when I don't want to endanger a larger camera.

I would not count on an SLR like your 20D being any better at dust protection.  From my understanding of burning man, dust *will* get into anything and everything.

Comment: Good point, I was going to consider the Dicapac since it's so cheap (like $20) and even if it's not ergonomic, could at least allow for a few clumsy shots for sunrises/big events/etc.